# What is the Best Practice for finishing the walls of a Bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, painting, wallpaper

I am currently stripping back the layers of wallpaper in a bathroom and I am a relatively amateur DIY-er.

As I have removed the paper, patches of the plaster have become exposed as small bits of the (assumedly) latex primer have come away. Is it therefore better to remove all of that layer and start afresh with a new layer of primer? It is intended for the wall to be painted.

The decor is coming down as part of a larger bathroom refit, although I will be getting in a professional to do the actual bathroom furniture aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to fill in the depressions left by the bits of plaster that have fallen off in order to get the wall smooth again. You can get ready-mix plaster compound at any hardware store; just add water and follow the directions. Once it's hardened, paint away.

Comment: Hi @iLikeDirt.  I have the plaster mix all ready to do any (or rather all the years of) hole filling; but can I then paint straight onto it? I thought that was a no-no?

Comment: It's fine, especially if your walls are real plaster instead of drywall. Plaster is much more moisture-resistant. You can paint right over it if you use a paint that is self-priming; otherwise prime over everything first and then paint over that. Don't use latex-based primer/paint to paint over oil-based paint.